# JS executing only once for first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have js which execute only for first div (#addcommentform), if i put more forms on one page = the problem

how to get js working for every form on page?
Thank you

```
$(function(){


var working = false;

$('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if(working) return false;

    working = true;
    $('#submit').val('Working..');
    $('span.error').remove();

    $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

        working = false;
        $('#submit').val('Submit');

        if(msg.status){


            $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
            $('#body').val('');
        }
        else {


            $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
            });
        }
    },'json');

});
```

})

Comment: __IDs must be unique.__ The problem occurs when you are using same id multiple times. Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: You are attaching an event handler to one form only. How do you expect it to handle submits of multiple forms?

Comment: i am really amateur in js :(

Comment: Do you even understand what `$('#addCommentForm')` is and does? It's pretty basic stuff

Comment: @Hobbycoder, Can you post your HTML? I am sure you are using `id="addCommentForm"` multiple times in HTML. Convert it to `class="addCommentForm"` in HTML then use `$('.addCommentForm')` instead of `$('#addCommentForm')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving the divs IDs of "addCommentForm", set their classes to "addCommentForm".  Then change your code to use the class selector .addCommentForm rather than the hashtag ID selector, i.e.:

```
$('.addCommentForm').submit(function(e){
```